# Every Hausdorff Lindelöf P-space is normal

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $X$ is

- *Lindelöf* if every open cover of $X$ has a countable subcover.
- a *P-space* if every countable intersection of open sets is open.

How do you show the following:

> Every Hausdorff Lindelöf P-space is normal.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show that $X$ is regular (because regular Lindelöf spaces are normal).

So take a closed set $F\subseteq X$ and a point $a$ not in $F$.  For each $x\in F$ there exist disjoint open nbhds $U_x$ and $V_x$ of $x$ and $a$ respectively.  Since $F$ is closed in a Lindelöf space, it is also Lindelöf.  So $F$ is covered by countably many of the $U_x$.  By the P-space property the (countable) intersection of the corresponding $V_x$ is an open nbhd of $a$. It is disjoint from the union of those $U_x$, which form an open nbhd of $F$.  This proves $X$ is regular.